# How to print only the value of group 2 in preg_match_all without the array and without loops

Tags: php, curl

How to print only the value of  group 2 in preg_match_all without the array and without loops

```
$url = 'https://hentaifox.com/gallery/58091/';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match_all('!<a href="\/tag\/(.*?)\/"><span class="badge tag">(.*?)<\/span><\/a>!', $result, $tags);
```

I only want (.*?) result to use it any where

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Do not switch `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$group2=$tags[1];
print_r($group2);
```

but! [Do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), use proper HTML parsing tools instead, in this case

```
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($result);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach ($xp->query("//a[contains(@href,'/tag/')]/span[1]") as $tag) {
    $tags[] = trim($tag->textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to do something like that ?

```
$matches = preg_match_all('!<a href="\/tag\/(.*?)\/"><span class="badge tag">(.*?)<\/span><\/a>!', $result, $tags);
$group_2 = $matches[2][0][0];
```

(I'm no expert, so maybe you will have to change the numbers a little bit...)